# What is benefit to use context trigger piecewise hashing over traditional piecewise hashing?

Tags: c, algorithm, hash

Original piecewise hashing uses fixed-size segment of a file to evaluate a hash value. 
And I found some piecewise hashing such as context trigger piecewise hashing uses rolling hash to trigger when to evaluate a hash value of a file.

And I'm quite not sure a point to use this technique over traditional one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean "Context Triggered Piecewise Hashing"?

The [ssdeep project](http://ssdeep.sourceforge.net/) links to a paper called "Identifying almost identical files using context triggered piecewise hashing", by Jesse Kornblum. That paper covers the origin and goals of CTPH in the form of the spamsum algorithm.

To summarize:

- Computing a full file hash, such as by running `sha1sum file`, allows you to find pairs of files that are exactly the same, in time linear in the total size of the files.
- Using fixed-size segments for piecewise hashing means that if bytes are re-written in the middle of a file, you can probably still identify that it's the same as a reference file. However, if bytes are inserted or deleted, then the checksums for the entire rest of the file change.
- CTPH should allow recognizing the similarity between files even in the presence of more substantial differences. As long as the changes aren't too large, CTPH can handle inserting or deleting portions of the file. The paper claims that given just the first third or the final third of a file, spamsum can recognize which file it probably came from.